# I want to print two interleaved triangles. But my code is not giving me my desired output. What changes should I make in my code?

Tags: c++

I want to print two interleaved triangles. But my code is not giving me my desired output. What changes should I make in my code?

```
*
+++++
**
++++
***
+++
****
++
*****
+
```

Following program will print two interleaved triangles of characters * and +

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;
int main ()
{
    int a ;     //declaration for outer loop
    int b ;     //declaration for inner loop

    for ( a=0 ; a <= 9 ; a++ )          //this is outer loop. it will control the number of line for any shape
    {
        //this condition wil print * pattern followed by + pattern in an alternate sequence 
        if ( a%2 == 0)
        {
            for ( b=0 ; b <= a ; b++ )      //this is the inner loop. it will control how much chracters will be printed in a line
            {   
            cout << "*" ;                   //wahtever the chracter is there in the double quotes will be printed as per working of loop. here is the * chracter
            }   
        }

        //this condition wil print pattern followed by * pattern in an alternate sequence
        if ( a%2 != 0 )
        {
            for ( b=9 ; b >= a ; b-- )      //this is the inner loop. it will control how much chracters will be printed in a line
            {   
            cout << "+" ;                   //wahtever the chracter is there in the double quotes will be printed as per working of loop. here is the + chracter
            }   
        }

        cout << endl ;                  //it will end each line after each incerment in the loop
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You could simplify your code a lot by iterating from `0` to `4` (instead of from `0` to `9`) and removing the `if` conditions.

Comment: What is the question? It already looks exactly like you showed: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/736ebac506ce1901 (maybe it's because I corrected a dozen spelling errors in the comments?)